# How to create object arrays with classes that have constructors in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor

```
class Time {
private:
    int hour = 0;
    int minute = 0;
public:
    Time(int hour, int minute);
    void setHour(int hour);
    void setMinute(int minute);
    int getHour();
    int getMinute();
    void print();
    void advance();
};
Time::Time(int h, int m) // DONE
{
    hour = h;
    minute = m;
    if (hour > 23) 
    {
        hour = 0;
    }
    if (minute > 59) 
    {
        minute = 0;
    }
}
void Time::setHour(int h) // DONE
{
    if (h > 23) 
    {
        hour = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        hour = h;
    }
}
void Time::setMinute(int m) // DONE
{
    if (m > 59) 
    {
        minute = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        minute = m;
    }
}
int Time::getHour() // DONE
{
    return hour;
}
int Time::getMinute() // DONE
{
    return minute;
}
void Time::print() // DONE
{
    string period;
    string minutezero;
    
    if (hour > 12) 
    {
        hour = hour - 12;
        period = "PM";
    }
    else if (hour < 13) 
    {
        period = "AM";
    }
    if (hour == 0) 
    {
        hour = 12;
        period = "AM";
    }
    if (minute < 10)
    {
        cout << hour << ":" << "0" << minute << " " << period;
    }
    else if (minute > 9)
    {
        cout << hour << ":" << minute << " " << period;
    }

}
void Time::advance() // DONE
{
    minute = minute + 1;
    if (minute == 60) 
    {
        minute = 0;
        hour = hour + 1;
    }
    if (hour == 24) 
    {
        hour = 0;
    }
}
```

On my int main function, I would like to create an array like
Time t[5] that will hold 5 time objects. How would I code this?

Here is what my module says word for word:

**Modify Time class to set up constructor(s) so the following
Time objects can be created in the driver. Set up a Time array as specified below and
print the times in the driver as well (can add to regular version and submit one version).

Time t1; // hour: 0, minute: 0, 12:00 AM

Time t2(8); // hour: 8, minute: 0, 8:00 AM

Time t3(13, 30); // hour: 13, minute: 30, 1:30 PM

Time t4(25, 5); // hour: 0, minute: 5, 12:05 AM

Time t4(12, 60); // hour: 12, minute: 0, 12:00 PMI**

Comment: Your `Time` class needs a default constructor.  Currently it only has a constructor that takes two parameters.  I suggest you create another constructor that takes no parameters and just initializes its members to zero.

Comment: Actually, on reading the subsequent requirements, it appears you need to support construction with only the hour too.  In that case you can get away with declaring default parameter values for the existing constructor.

Comment: wait.. do original requirement suggest that day got 25 hours in it? lol (24 hour day : 24 == 0)

Answer (score 1):

As paddy pointed out in a comment you need a default constructor that would look something like this:

```
Time::Time() : hour(0), minute(0) { }
```

And you also need a constructor with only the hour as a parameter

```
Time::Time(int h) : hour(h), minute(0) {
    if (hour > 23) hour = 0;
}
```

After that your class would look something like this

```
public:
    Time();
    Time(int h);
    Time(int hour, int minute);
    void setHour(int hour);
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
 
int main(){
    std::vector<Time> t;
    std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(t), 5, Time(0, 0));
}
```

Or use pointers

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<Time>, 5> t;  // std::unique_ptr<Time> t[5];
```

According to the requirement `Time t1; // hour: 0, minute: 0, 12:00 AM` you have to add and implement the default constructor `Time::Time()`, or yet better if you make only one `Time::Time(int hour = 0, int minute = 0)` with default parameter values.

A bit update:

```
class Time {
private:
    int hour = 0;
    int minute = 0;
public:
    Time(int hour = 0, int minute = 0);
    // skipped
```